# How do I print data after fitting data into a pipeline?

Tags: python, svm, scipy

I was using 3 functions form scipy: TFIDF vectorizer, Multioutput classifier and  Linear SVC.

The code goes like this.

`pipe_lr1 = Pipeline(steps=[('cv',TfidfVectorizer()), ('lr_multi',MultiOutputClassifier(LinearSVC()))])`

How can I print the values at each step of the function in order to see

- What was the ouptput of TFIDF vectorizer?
- What was the output of Linear SVC?
- What data was coming out of MultioutputClassifier(X)?

Comment: Imho you're not starting from the beginning: start with a simple tutorial, maybe [this one](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) for instance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469633/how-to-transform-items-using-sklearn-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You can access them using the below code. Do what you normally do without using a pipeline.

```py
pipe_lr1.named_steps["cv"]
pipe_lr1.named_steps["lr_multi"]
```

Comment: This was not printing any values

Comment: This is not print anything; it gives you access to TfidfVectorizer and MultiOutputClassifier. Then use their functions. For example  `pipe_lr1.named_steps["cv"].get_feature_names_out()`